# Play Framework cause ValidationException when @Column(nullable = false)

Tags: validation, annotations, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Play Framework 2.0. 
I have a class (A) which have 2 interfaces (IA and IB).
class A have a number of variables, say x, y, z. 
IA and IB have their own CRUD pages, controlled by different controllers. (IAController and IBController), where x is controller by IA and y, z is controlled by IB.
x, y, z all have a   @Column(nullable = false) annotation. 
The problem is, when I update y and z using IBController, it will cause a ValidationException on x (I know this because if I remove the annotation on x, the exception disappeared).

I'm just wonder if any encountered the same problem.

Below are my Exception trace:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ValidationException: validation failed for: models.t1d.A]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
com.avaje.ebean.ValidationException: validation failed for: models.t1d.Visit
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.validate(PersistRequestBean.java:461) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeUpdateBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:89) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:485) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:511) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.update(DefaultPersister.java:417) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.forceUpdateStateless(DefaultPersister.java:253) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
```